# Cannot use click() in Selenium with mobile emulated chromedriver

Tags: android, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, infragistics

I'm trying to test the login process of an internal web application using a mobile emulated chrome browser. I am using Python 3.6.4.

It finds the element by name, but won't click it!

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
enter code herefrom selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

mobile_emulation = {

    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },

    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)

driver.get("https://internalweburlhere")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtEmailAddress")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Username")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword")
elem.send_keys("1234")
print("Password Entered")
driver.find_element_by_id("btnSignIn").click()
print("Logged In")
```

Here is the website source:

```
<div id="divSignIn" class="login-content-sign-in" style="display:block;">
<div id="divSignInHeader" class="login-content-header text-bold-10 label-colour" MandatoryField="False">Sign in using your Portal account</div>
<div id="divSignInMessage" class="login-content-sign-in-message success-label-colour text-bold-9" MandatoryField="False" style="DISPLAY:none;">Your account email address has now been verified, please enter your password and sign in</div>
<div id="upSignIn">
<div id="divSignInEmailAddress">
<div id="lblEmailAddress" class="entry-label">Enter your email address</div>
<div>
<input name="txtEmailAddress" type="email" id="txtEmailAddress" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" class="login-content-email-address entry-control entry-control-colour entry-control-border text-9" onkeyup="checkSignInButton()" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="divPassword">
<div id="lblPassword" class="entry-label" MandatoryField="False">Enter your password</div>
<div>
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" class="login-content-password entry-control entry-control-colour entry-control-border text-9" onkeypress="checkCapsLockStatus(event,&#39;divSignInCapsLock&#39;)" onblur="hideCapsLockStatus(&#39;divSignInCapsLock&#39;)" onkeyup="checkSignInButton()" />
<div id="divSignInCapsLock" class="login-caps-lock-status">
<div id="divCapsLockDetail">
<img src="/Portal_Benchmark/Static/5.8.0.192/Images/dlg_icon_Exclamation.png" class="login-caps-lock-image" />
<span id="lblCapsLockMessage" class="login-caps-lock-message text-8" MandatoryField="False">Caps Lock Is On</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="divSignInCaptcha" class="login-content-sign-in-captcha">
<div id="lblSignInCaptcha" class="entry-label">Enter the captcha text shown below </div>
<input type="hidden" id="objSignInCaptcha_clientState" name="objSignInCaptcha_clientState" /><div id="objSignInCaptcha" class="ig_Control igc_Control"><div class="igc_CaptchaImageArea"><img src="WebCaptchaImage.axd?guid=588a4174-70ca-4bf6-ac10-7ac77f74e6a4" title="" alt="" height="60" width="175" class="igc_CaptchaImage" /><input type="hidden" id="objSignInCaptcha__SignInEditor_clientState" name="objSignInCaptcha__SignInEditor_clientState" /><input title="{0}" id="objSignInCaptcha__SignInEditor" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="checkSignInButton()" readonly="readonly" name="objSignInCaptcha__SignInEditor" maxlength="8" class="igc_CaptchaInput igte_Edit" type="text" style="width:175px;text-align:notset;" /></div><div class="igc_RefreshAndAudioButtonsArea"><a href="WebCaptchaImage.axd?guid=588a4174-70ca-4bf6-ac10-7ac77f74e6a4&amp;audio=true"><img alt="Listen to Captcha Audio" id="x:1812979435.0:mkr:AudioButton" src="Static/5.8.0.192/PortalStyleSheets/Infragistics/Default/images/igc_AudioButton.gif" /></a><a id="x:1812979435.1:mkr:RefreshButtonLink" href="#"><img alt="Refresh Captcha Image" id="x:1812979435.2:mkr:RefreshButton" src="Static/5.8.0.192/PortalStyleSheets/Infragistics/Default/images/igc_RefreshButton.gif" /></a></div><div style="clear:left;"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="login-content-sign-in-panel">
<div id="lblError" class="login-content-sign-in-error warning-label-colour text-bold-9">
</div>
<div class="login-content-sign-in-button">
<input name="btnSignIn" type="submit" id="btnSignIn" disabled="disabled" value="Sign In" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anybody suggest how I might get around this? Interestingly, when I run similar code at BrowserStack on an android chrome browser, the clicks work as intended. Just not when I run it locally.

Comment: can you put some wait before click on submit, your button is disabled so it require some time to get enable after performing necessary validation. you can use `time.sleep` method to add wait for debugging purpose. Let me know further

Comment: @NarendraR - Have tried that but no joy. The site source code is before I have entered anything in the username and password field. Once I have entered the password, the disabled="disabled" part is removed.

Comment: Can you try using javascriptexecutor

Comment: try like this `element = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSignIn")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thank you. I wonder why my original code didn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time element present in DOM but selenium failed to wait until the attribute get removed . Possible guess is In your case it is not waiting for remove attribute  `disabled="disabled"` from your `input` tag and performing the click, even you can't see any exception.

So in such case you have to inject javascript in your browser and perform the action as given below :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSignIn")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Comment: Calling `HTMLElement.click()` with a script injection makes the test useless since it doesn't simulate a Click from a user point of view. It doesn't check if a real user can click the element and it also skips most of the related events which could be expected by the page. Thus it should never be used in a test.

Comment: @FlorentB. I'm agree with your concern. But can you suggest some alternatives to get rid from these kind of situation.

Comment: it depends on the cause of the issue which needs to be investigated by monitoring the events and state of the page. It could be a timing issue which can be resolved with an explicit wait or a sleep if there's a fixed delay due to an animation. It could also be a bug in the driver, in which case it needs be reported with a reproducible example.